# Modulus formula

Tags: c++, algorithm, modulus

I'm reading a C++ Primer 5th ed and i don't understand why is this true :

> The modulus operator is defined so that if m and n are integers and n is nonzero,
>   then (m/n)*n + m%n is equal to m.

I decided to check this and the result was indeed true:

```
int m = 9;
int n = 2;
if ((m / n)*n + m%n == m)
    std::cout << "true" << std::endl;
```

1) (m/n)*n == m (9)

2) m%n == 1

3) (m/n)*n + m%n == 10 NOT 9

Can somebody explain what is going on here?

Comment: `(9/2)*2` does **not** equal `9`.

Comment: Do you understand how integer division works?

Comment: The real culprit of this definition is actually in negative integers.. try -9 ... :) (after you get the idea of integer division first, as answers point out).

Comment: @Ped7g - the definition holds for negative integers too.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth that's the point... which means, that the remainder will be -1, which may be surprising for some people (at least for me it was, before I looked on it better and understood it fully).

Comment: @Ped7g Actually, with 9 and 2, -1 is mathematically correct (too). (But I know you mean that the CPU thinks `(-a % b) == (a % -b) == -(a%b)` which is not always mathematically correct)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(m/n)*n == m (9)
```

You did that calculation wrong. This are *integers*

```
9/2 == 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this code to see that you get the expected result.

The reason why you did not verify it manually is this:

> (m/n)*n == m (9)

While it is 9 in mathematics, in C++ it is 8. This is because C++ drops fractional part when dividing integers.

Answer (score 0):

**Nope, `(9/4)*4`, for example, is not 9!** (It's actually 8)

In C and C++, whenever you're dividing integers, the result is still an integer, so `9/4`, for example, is exactly 2 (the fractional part got truncated). And because of this truncation the formula works.